# Updating fields with the case statement

Tags: sql, case

For the following People in the query results below the UniqueIDSuffix value should be padded with leading 0's for a character length = 6. After UniqueIDSuffix modify, UniqueID value should be updated to character length = 9 via UniqueIDPrefix + UniqueIDSuffix = UniqueID

```
select * from cph..cppat (nolock) where 
UniqueIDPrefix is not null and 
UniqueIDPrefix <> 'VIS' and len(UniqueIDSuffix) < 6
```

order by UniqueIDPrefix asc

The statement I have is:

```
SET UniqueIDsuffix  =
        (CASE
           WHEN UniqueIDsuffix = 3 THEN '000' + UniqueIDsuffix  ELSE
           When UniqueIDsuffix = 4 THEN '00' + UniqueIDsuffix ELSE
           WHEN UniqueIDsuffix = 5 Then '0' + UniqueIDsuffix ELSE
           WHEN UniqueIDsuffix = 6 THEN UniqueIDsuffix ELSE
           )
where UniqueIDPrefix is not null and UniqueIDPrefix <> 'VIS' 
and len(UniqueIDSuffix) < 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the update statement . . . and you have extraneous `else` statements . . . and you are missing the `len()` function from the comparison:

```
update cph..cppat
    SET UniqueIDsuffix  =
            (CASE WHEN len(UniqueIDsuffix) = 3 THEN '000' + UniqueIDsuffix 
                  When len(UniqueIDsuffix) = 4 THEN '00' + UniqueIDsuffix 
                  WHEN len(UniqueIDsuffix) = 5 Then '0' + UniqueIDsuffix 
                  WHEN len(UniqueIDsuffix) = 6 THEN UniqueIDsuffix 
            )
    where UniqueIDPrefix is not null and UniqueIDPrefix <> 'VIS' and len(UniqueIDSuffix) < 6
```

By the way, you can express this more simply as:

```
update cph..cppat
    SET UniqueIDsuffix  = right('0000000'+UniqueIDSuffix, 6)
    where UniqueIDPrefix is not null and UniqueIDPrefix <> 'VIS' and len(UniqueIDSuffix) < 6
```